# Apache Kafka: Lowering `request.timeout.ms` causes metadata fetch failures?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a 9 broker, 5 node Zookeeper Kafka setup.

In order to reduce the time for reporting failures, we had set `request.timeout.ms` to 3000. However, with this setting, I'm observing some weird behavior.

Occasionally, I'm seeing client (producer) getting an error:

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.`

This doesn't happen always. There are some producers that work just fine.

When I bumped up the `request.timeout.ms` value, I didn't see any errors.

Any idea why lowering `request.timeout.ms` cause metadata fetch timeouts?

Comment: Its a config using which u can specify, how long the client will wait to get a response after sending a request. Keeping it too low, could incur duplicates., due to unnecessary producer retries. As for the metadata exception which ur getting is because ur requests are timing out for metadata refresh.

Comment: The metadata request can be sent to any broker, because each broker has a metadata cache which stores this information. Seems like a slow network connection to me.

Comment: @IndraneelBende Thanks for the quick tip. I understand the config option and the error independently. What I'm trying to figure out is why should the `request.timeout.ms` cause the Fetch metadata timeout?

Comment: Request.timeout.ms is meant for any kind of request whether it is produce, metadata or any other kind of request. Request.timeout.ms is not special to only one kind of request.